# How can I run a script from an scpecific node and activating a conda environment?

Tags: python, environment-variables, qsub

I have a python program that runs inside a conda environment installed in a specific node of a cluster. I would like to submit it into qsub but just need help.
My script is:

```
#!/bin/bash
source conda activate myenv
pyhton3.6 myprogram.py
```

I have already tried:

- ```
  ssh **node** 'export SGE_ROOT=/usr/local/run/ge2011.11; /usr/local/run/ge2011.11/bin/linux-x64/qsub script.sh'
  ```

  but says

  ```
  Unable to run job: denied: host "**node**" is no submit hot. Exiting
  ```
- ```
  qsub cwd -V qu=**node** script.sh
  ```

  but says

  ```
  Unable to read script because of error: error opening cwd;error opening qu=**node**
  ```

Thanks!

Comment: So what is installed on the node?  AFAIR, your script must be installed on the submit host (on a disk accessible to the submit host), the particular environment and such may only be on the specific node as long as you ensure it only runs on that node.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is a detour but I did:

1. Login the node
2. Include in myscript.py:

```
#!/anaconda3path/bin/python3.6
```

3. Run as:

```
nohup python3.6 myprogram.py > NNp.out &
```

Problem solved!